# Уточнение типа поля в классе

Tags: классы, mvc, java

Добрый день

Пишу нубокласс для mvc, конкретно controller.
Начал с абстрактного класса:

```
public abstract class Controller {
    protected View view;

    public Controller(View v) {
        view = v;
    }

    protected void render() {
        data();
        view.setData(data);
        view.render();
        listeners();
        if (display)
            view.open();
    }
    protected void data() {}

    protected void listeners() {}
}
```

Вот так его использовать собирался:

```
public class AboutController extends Controller {

    public AboutController() {
        super(new AboutView());
        super.render();
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что `protected View view` может быть любым другим `View` который расширяет другой абстрактный класс `View` (`AboutView` например) и естественно я не смогу взять поле или метод который не описан в `View` но есть в `AboutView` (т.к. получиться вроде...`View view = new AboutView()`). Можно как-то в контроллерах уточнять какой именно это `View`?

Собственно я понимаю что где-то ошибка в самой архитектуре классов, но я уже неделю голову ломаю как это реализовать(

Answer (score 1):

Все удивительно просто)

```
public abstract class Controller<T extends View> {
    protected T view;

    public Controller(T v) {
        view = v;
    }

    protected void render() {
        data();
        view.setData(data);
        view.render();
        listeners();
        if (display)
            view.open();
    }
    protected void data() {}

    protected void listeners() {}
}
```

Comment: Это да, но может я и ошибаюсь, разве контроллер должен зависить от вьюхи?

Comment: Тоесть, нужно и модель тогда кинуть параметром

Comment: http://www.austintek.com/mvc/ вот неплохой ресурс